# what is this user 'system:unsecured' in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Does anyone know what this 'system:unsecured' user is? we are seeing api requests from this user from within the control plane itself.

Comment: This is one of the few references I have found about that. The main topic of the article is about a vulnerability, still it might be that it does not have to do with your log entries, but maybe it helps you.

https://www.alcide.io/new-kubernetes-node-vulnerability-cve-2020-8558-bypasses-localhost-boundary/

Answer (score 0):

A request to the control plane, specifically the API server component, can be achieved via connecting to the externally facing port that requires authentication/authorization or connect to the internal port (only reachable from within the host) that does not require authentication/authorization. The second one is a vulnerability and should be avoided.

When someone/something connects to the insecure port, K8s will assign the activity to this user system:unsecured as there is "no" user.

More info: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/91506